# Writing the woman's name in a kasubah or get: Plonis *ben* Ploni

Tags: halacha, names, women, mistakes, legal-documents

Instead of writing the name of the kallah (bride) Rivka *bat* Chaim (for example) it was written Rivka *ben* Chaim. In such a case what's the halacha? By a kasubah is it valid? Does it have to be written again? What about in the case of a get is it kosher? Should another get be written and given?

Comment: "Kosher" is probably the wrong technical term; a Kesuba is a legal document that is either valid or invalid.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Why can't kosher mean valid?

Comment: Kosher can mean anything you want it to mean - but it usually means that it's "halachicly valid". If a Get is not Kosher then the couple is not divorced. It's not Kosher if it's not written with all the complicated rules of Gittin. A Kesuba has no Halachic ramifications; best to show it to a lawyer...